# IndexError: list index out of range; trying to pass as argument

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to write a script that lets me read data from a few files I generated (they have a set naming scheme). But I keep getting the above IndexError when I try to run it.

```
before = [29, 22, 21]
after = [6, 6, 1]
prop = ['n_force', 'n_force_sub', 'x_force', 'x_force_sub']

for pi in prop:
    for m in before:
        t, fn = np.genfromtxt("peg_4_60_shear_{0}.{1}.{2}".format(before[m],after[m],prop[pi]),unpack=True, skiprows=2)
```

**EDIT | QUESTION RESOLVED:** I resolved it by converting the `before` and `after` arrays into strings, and changing the code to the following:

```
before = ['29', '22', '21']
after = ['6', '6', '1']  
prop = ['n_force', 'n_force_sub', 'x_force', 'x_force_sub']        

for l in range(0,3):
      for m in range(0,2):
          t, fn = np.genfromtxt("peg_4_60_shear_{0}.{1}.{2}".format(before[m], after[m], prop[l]) ,unpack=True, skiprows=2)
```

I had more code after that to print the grabbed data, but now I'm working on saving the data to a file or something. Thanks, everyone :)

Comment: `before = [29, 22, 21` doesn't run. post your **actual** code. Also, post the complete error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m` loops over `before` and will get the values `29, 22, 21` in sequence.

`before` and `after` don't have 30 elements, so `before[m]` (before[29]) will break.

If you want to loop over both sequences at once, it's better to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up the values, something like;

```
for pi in prop:
  for b,a in zip(before, after):
    t, fn = np.genfromtxt("peg_4_60_shear_{0}.{1}.{2}".format(b, a, prop[pi]),unpack=True, skiprows=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with 2 different lists, you need to `zip()` them together to loop over it.

```
for pi, m in zip(prop, before):
    t, fn = np.genfromtxt("peg_4_60_shear_{0}.{1}.{2}".format(before[m],after[m],prop[pi]),unpack=True, skiprows=2)
```